Why is pip installing packages that don't appear to be required?
In a new venv I can see the only thing installed is pip
>pip list --not-required
Package Version
------- -------
pip     24.3.1

After installing jupyter with
pip install jupyter

I now see several required packages that do not appear to be transitive dependencies of jupyter. According to the help output the --note-required flag is supposed to "List packages that are not dependencies of installed packages."
>pip list --not-required
Package      Version
------------ -------
fqdn         1.5.1
isoduration  20.11.0
jsonpointer  3.0.0
jupyter      1.1.1
pip          24.3.1
uri-template 1.3.0
webcolors    24.8.0

So if those extra packages are not required by any other package, why were they installed?
If I install pipdeptree and run it, it shows the same packages as tree roots. (pipdeptree has been added to the list and pip has been removed because it is required by pipdeptree)
>pipdeptree -d 0
fqdn==1.5.1
isoduration==20.11.0
jsonpointer==3.0.0
jupyter==1.1.1
pipdeptree==2.23.4
uri-template==1.3.0
webcolors==24.8.0


The jupyter package on pypi.org is a metapackage. While it doesn't currently list the other packages ypu are finding, if the other packages it lists are also metapackages it may be pulling them in (I didn't dig that deep). If you only want the notebook it is pip install notebook
